# What did I do wrong?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, chess

My friend and I were bored so we decided to play a game of chess. I lost, for I have done something bad. I was a beginner, so I could not find where I went wrong.

I wanted to know what was wrong, so I asked my friend, she did not reply. I decided to sleep. Next day I saw this on my table.

[image]

```
1. f4
1. c4 c6 2. Nf3 d5 3. b3
1. c4 e5 2. Nc3
1. c4 e6 2. Nf3 d5 3. g3 Nf6 4. Bg2 Be7 5. O-O
1. Nf3
1. Nf3 Nf6
1. c4 Nf6 2. Nc3 e6 3. e4

1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. g3 g6 4. Bg2 Bg7 5. d3 d6
1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3
1. e4 c5 2. f4
1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 dxe4 4. Nxe4 Bf5

1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Bb4 4. e5 c5
1. e4 e5 2. d4 exd4
1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nd2 Nf6
1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nd2 Nf6
1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bg5 Be7 5. e5 Nfd7 6. Bxe7 Qxe7
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The numeric parts of the respective [ECO codes of these openings](//www.365chess.com/eco.php), when converted to letters by A→1, B→2, …, Z→26, spell out BLUNDER YOUR QUEEN. So I guess what you did wrong was to [blunder](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blunder_(chess)) your queen.